# Is my MySQL query right?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a error with a php script and I am not quite sure that my join query is right?

```
$sql15 = mysql_query("select  userid, Reciver, Sender , proimg from Friends JOIN users ON(Reciver ='$fullname' or Sender ='$fullname') where accepted = 2") or die("ERROR Please refresh the page and try again"); 
$Fri = mysql_num_rows($sql15);
```

and this is the other one which I think is the problem

```
$sql12 =  mysql_query("select * from Friends where (Reciver = '$fullname' or Sender = '$fullname')") or die("ERROR Please refresh the page and try again"); 
$Friends = mysql_num_rows($sql12);
```

Question: What is wrong with my mysql querys?

Comment: Are there any error messages displayed?

Comment: No it just doesn't do what its made 2 do its gives me a 1 and I should give me 2

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what the queries are supposed to accomplish? And some sample data.

Comment: this one $sql15 = mysql_query("select  userid, Reciver, Sender , proimg from Friends JOIN users ON(Reciver ='$fullname' or Sender ='$fullname') where accepted = 2") or die("ERROR Please refresh the page and try again"); 
$Fri = mysql_num_rows($sql15);  should give me a 2 as he has 2 friends and the first one is suppose 2 join the tables so i can get a users picture.

Answer (score 2):

No, your `JOIN` syntax is not right.  `JOIN` should be used to, well, *join* tables.  For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM friends
JOIN users ON friends.user_id = users.id
```

This would join the table "friends" with the table "users" by comparing the columns specified.

Your current `JOIN` clause is comparing fields to variables -- essentially trying to use it like a `WHERE` clause.  This won't throw an error, but it also won't do any joining.

The MySQL docs are quite good:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html  You should give them a read and test your SQL either using the Workbench app or the MySQL command line.  These tools will give you much better feedback than using `or die...` in PHP.